# Error in ceres when trying to install opencv-python on Mac m1

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I am trying to install opencv-python on the Mac m1.

I have followed the instructions here:

https://sayak.dev/install-opencv-m1/

However I am getting an error in a c++ library when running the make -j8 command:

```
/opt/homebrew/include/ceres/internal/integer_sequence_algorithm.h:64:21: error: no template named 'integer_sequence' in namespace 'std'; did you mean '__integer_sequence'?
```

What do I need to do to fix this error?

In one of the files which is showing an error it looks like this:

```
// Checks, whether the given parameter block sizes are valid. Valid means every
// dimension is bigger than zero.
constexpr bool IsValidParameterDimensionSequence(std::integer_sequence<int>) {
  return true;
}
```

It seems like valid C++ but not really sure why its breaking

Comment: Make sure your compiler is set to compile to the C++14 Standard or a more recent standard.

Comment: How do I check which version I have and how to change it?

Comment: Weirdly in my error log its saying that the C++ used is 11

Comment: My knowledge of Mac programming tools is minimal. I'm afraid I can't help you find the correct setting to change. It should be obvious once you find it though, if that's any comfort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error was in the CMakeLists.txt in the opencv repo.

I had to edit this file and set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)  to get it to work

Comment: Great / simple answer....  Thanks very much